# Gravar texto em Shell Script

Tags: linux, script, shell-script, shell

Eu estou fazendo um Shell Script, e eu tenho que gravar uma grande quantidade de linhas em um único arquivo, como eu posso fazer isso de uma forma mais automática? Pois eu comecei a fazer de uma forma muito manual:

```
echo "primeira linha do arquivo" >> /diretorio/arquivo.txt
echo "segunda linha do arquivo" >> /diretorio/arquivo.txt
```

É possível eu colocar todas as linhas em um único comando? Exemplo:

```
echo "primeira linha
segunda linha
terceira linha
quarta linha
" >> /diretorio/arquivo.txt
```

Mas há algo mais, eu tenho algumas variáveis no meu script que eu preciso estar colocando nessas linhas em que serão gravadas, ficando mais o menos assim:

```
variavel1=primeira
variavel2=segunda
variavel3=terceira

echo "$variavel1 linha
$variavel2 linha
$variavel3 linha
quarta linha
" >> /diretorio/arquivo.txt
```

Eu já procurei em todos os lugares, mas não encontrei nada relacionado a isso.

Comment: Seria legal dizer o que o comando `cat` faz  ou postar um link com a explicação

Answer (score 3):

Existem diversas formas, uma é usando o comando `cat` e um delimitador:

```
cat >'arquivo.txt' <<EOT
aí você coloca
um monte de texto
e só precisa terminar
com o a mesma string usada
no delimitador.
EOT
```

Outra é usando uma função dentro do **Bash**:

```
function coisas_a_imprimir(){
    echo "a"
    echo "b"
}

coisas_a_imprimir > 'arquivo.txt'
```

A que considero mais "limpa" em **Bash** é usando uma *subshell*:

```
saida='arquivo.txt'

let variavel_1=1
let variavel_2=2

( echo "Isto é um exemplo de subshell"
  echo ${variavel_1}
  let variavel_2=3
  echo ${variavel_2} ) >$saida

echo $variavel_2
```

O único "problema" neste caso é o de escopo pois as variáveis criadas e/ou alteradas dentro dela não serão transferidas para a *shell* principal -- veja no exemplo o conteúdo da `variavel_2` dentro e fora da *subshell*.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a opção `-e` do `echo`, que permite que sejam colocados `\n` e estes sejam interpretados como quebras de linha:

```
echo -e "$variavel1 linha\n$variavel2 linha\n$variavel3 linha\nquarta linha"
```

Outra opção é usar o comando `printf`, que também aceita `\n` para quebras de linha:

```
printf "$variavel1 linha\n$variavel2 linha\n$variavel3 linha\nquarta linha"
```

---

A diferença é que o `echo` adiciona uma quebra de linha "extra" no final (no caso, depois de "quarta linha"), enquanto `printf` não (este precisaria ter um `\n` explícito no final).

Você pode fazer o `echo` não adicionar a quebra de linha no final com a opção `-n`:

```
echo -ne "$variavel1 linha\n$variavel2 linha\n$variavel3 linha\nquarta linha"
```

Ainda há outras diferenças entre esses dois comandos, e você pode ver [este link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o exec:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 1>> text.txt


#Echos

echo "foo"
echo "bar"
```